# Git Undo reverted commits from new branch?

Tags: git

I did this, simplifying and in "pseudo GIT"

```
In branch master, commit A
In branch master, commit B
Push to server
-- We see that there's a bug
In branch master, revert commit B, A
-- Now, to test what happened:
new branch TEST from old commit A
-- Looking at it, we find out that the issue was in somebody else's API,
--  so our original commit A was OK. They fix their API
```

What would you do here? What is the most elegant way to go back to A, just "revert the reverts"?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> What is the most elegant way to go back to A, just "revert the reverts"?

Yes. Anything else would involve rewriting history, and that's a terrible idea.

Answer (score 0):

It might not look like an elegant way, but it's the best way, if your commits were already pushed to the remote.

If you'd had same issue on your local machine, you could just reset those commits, overwriting history. This would result in cleaner history, but the problem is, that if you change you history, you either changing hash of the commit (you basically creating a new commit, you can't just edit), or you completely deleting your commits (like in your case).

If commits you want to change are already in the repo, then you gonna get a conflict. Git wont let you just overwrite those commits.

There is an option to force push though. You might consider it only if you work alone on the repo, or after consultation with the team.

In the end, reverting commits is not a bad idea, and I've seen a lot of situation, when there were revert after revert after revert, even in "clean" project. So I guess it's fine.